# Create unique string model.Name

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

How to make Name a unique because it's not a key it's a simple string.
The scenario is : you create some profit categories : you have Jackpot, salary, 
retired pay or etc. .After you choose one of this category and insert something in other controller.But dont need to have two categories with same names . I need only unique profit categories.Because Now I can create 100 categories with name "Salary" and different Id's because Id's autoIncrement Primary key.

```
  public ActionResult Create(ProfitCategoriesModel profitcategoriesmodel)
        {
            var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
            var addCategory = new ProfitCategoriesModel
            {
                Name = profitcategoriesmodel.Name,
                IdUser = user,
                Id = profitcategoriesmodel.Id,
            };
          db.ProfitCategories.Add(addCategory);
            db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Append a value at the end of the name or a Guid as Andrey has suggested

Comment: [Required]
            public string Name { get; set; }    
this is a value in my profitCategoriesModel

Comment: Explain your scenario in the question. What do you mean by a `unique Name` ?

Comment: I think what you'll need is a unique constraint on the `Name` column in your database. This prevents you from having multiple rows with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

Comment: What i want to say is : I don't want have two records "Salary" in my db .

Comment: @user2026573 I don't understand what you mean.